# What is the difference between 'created_at' and 'available_at'?

Tags: balanced-payments

Context for question: response given after [creating a new debit using Python library](https://docs.balancedpayments.com/current/api.html?language=python#create-a-new-debit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`created_at` is the timestamp of when the debit was created. `available_at` is when funds will arrive in the escrow balance, available for use -- these are often not the same because ACH debits take time to propagate. This will normally be 1-2 business days after the debit was created for an ACH debit, or instantly for a credit card debit.